# How to add elements to every element in data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have a "data" which is parsed from a CSV file.

However, I want to create a copy of it but with more elements to it. The elements will be added through a function. How can I do this?

Would it be like this? Data is old data. updateData is new data.

```
var visualization(data){
    var updateData = function(data){

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question right now is *unclear*. You may want to better explain your goals.

Comment: doesn't look related to d3.js

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, I'm using [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to create a (shallow) copy of the array so I can safely mutate it.

```
var visualization(data) {
    var updatedData = data.slice();
    // you can now safely manipulate updatedData, e.g. 
    // updatedData.push('something')
}
```